# unable to run npm install in docker image (getting auth error)?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install

I have a very simple Dockerfile

```
FROM node:17.3.1 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:17.3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY --from=build /app/dist ./dist
CMD npm run start:prod
```

When running `docker build -t nestjs-hello-world .` I am getting the following error. I don't understand why it is needing to login to npm. It is using the default registry. Even tried specifying the default registry as part of the npm install command, just to make sure, but same error..

```
 => ERROR [build 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                  8.3s
------
 > [build 4/6] RUN npm install:
#8 8.230 npm notice 
#8 8.231 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.1.2 -> 8.3.1
#8 8.231 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.3.1>
#8 8.232 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.3.1` to update!
#8 8.233 npm notice 
#8 8.235 npm ERR! code E401
#8 8.237 npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
#8 8.238 npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
#8 8.239 npm ERR!     npm login
#8 8.251 
#8 8.252 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 8.252 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-20T00_08_48_935Z-debug.log
```

Any ideas why this is happening for me please?

Thanks

Comment: Taking a guess here but I bet you've got a custom NPM repo set locally and it's written those entries into `package-lock.json`. Try just copying over `package.json`

Comment: OMG what a rookie mistake, yep you were very right!! Thanks so much for that hint.. I have looked at EVERYTHING except for the package lock.. Thanks so much @Phil

Comment: Nothing rookie about it. Generated files are very easy to ignore / overlook

Comment: Not copying over  package.json means your dependencies are now floating. You should instead fix your auth problem,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phil I had the same problem and I managed to unblock my problem thanks to your comment

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
# copying packages first helps take advantage of docker layers
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install prettier -g

# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm install


 # Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "node", "dist/server.js" ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).